# Get the address of the changed cell

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to trigger a macro (dependant on cell address) whenever any dde linked cell value is changed.

I tried Workbook.SetLinkOnData and Worksheet_Calculate event (with a dummy formula to trigger the event), but the problem is that none of them returns the address of the updated cell.

So is there a way to get the address of the updated cell to use it with my macro?

This is my macro

```
Public Sub UpdateCell (Byval strTargetAddress as String)
    'Some code
End Sub
```

Thank u in advance.

Comment: It's a sledgehammer to crack a nut, but how about using a hidden tab that contains a copy of the table before the change. Each time there's a recalc, compare the tables for differences and then once you've identified them all, copy the table to the hidden tab for next time..

Comment: Thank u. I think this is the only solution to get it done.

Answer (score 0):

How about using the Worksheet Change event:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    'MsgBox Target.Address
    Call UpdateCell (Target.Address)
End Sub
```

Or if you are looking for a formula then this would do:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    If Sheet1.Range("A1").Value = "Yes" Then Call UpdateCell("A1")
End Sub
```

Comment: Unfortunately Worksheet_Change event is not triggered if cell contains a formula. It's only triggered if cell's value is changed manually.

Comment: Worksheet_Calculate event doesn't contain the target cell as an argument

Comment: Yes, sorry my mistake, I've updated my answer, using Calculate and then defining what change you are expecting before calling the rest of your code...

Comment: I got more than 300 cells and want to monitor all of them .. not only A1.

Comment: Are the 300 cells calling the same subroutine? if any of their value changes?

Comment: Yes they all call the same macro.. but the macro is dependant on the cell address.

Comment: To be honest I would probably re-write your UpdateCell code to do its job without a cell address (if possible)... Or I would amend the spreadsheet so you could use the Worksheet_Change event...